# Why was my account deleted?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Over the past month, I was searching for a good domain for my NGO... and came across various sites where I could find many interesting domain names.  I came and opened an account in the webmaster stackexchange forum to gain and share knowledge.

There, I found some answers to be outdated, or giving incomplete information.
So, I went to post one or two answers on the site-- in an endeavour to help other persons like me who might come searching for their queries.  This is something that I have been doing over the last couple of years on other sites like [TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/146828/partha-d) or [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8854526/partha-d).

However, today I met with an exquisite behaviour, that seemed to me quite humiliating and probably undemocratic too:  After *one of my **posts** were deleted* a week ago, ***...my account came to be deleted*** today !
And without any explanation or citing any reason whatsoever that I could see-- and maybe try to adapt my response accordingly-- with a good intention to participate in the *provide-free-and-shareable-knowledge-for-everyone-in-the-world* run !

Can moderators/editors/voters of the webmaster site help me understand my shortcoming and mend it in my future interactions ?

Comment: Are you asking this with a different account from the one that was deleted?

Comment: It appears it was deleted by another moderator because your posts had multiple links to the same site that we've been receiving other spam for. We really do not permit [recommendations for sites and resources](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here due to issues with spam. Accounts that possibly appear to be here for self-promotion are typically deleted to prevent that from reoccurring. I'd suggest in the future that you limit links to the same site and disclose any affiliations. For reference see: [How to not be a spammer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes. I created a new account with the same profile (Partha D.) and am not able to see anything from the previous account (created roughly a fortnight ago).

Comment: @dan Thank you for the clear explanation. I understand.